# Assign new value to an Array using Enhanced For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to find a way to assign values to an Array from the scanner input by using enhanced For loop.  But I don't see a way I can do it.

In the code below i have declared a getInput() method which loops through the Array and assign numbers from the scanner input.  But in case of enhanced For loop I can't really use something like this -

```
For(int i: baseData){
//basedata[i]=scanner.nextInt()}
```

because baseData array will not return any value as it iterates, so i thought how about iterating through scanner.nextInt() and assign values in the array, but scanner.nextInt() is not a array.
So what could the easy solution for this problem?

```
package com.ksk;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int[] baseData = new int[4];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers here");
    getInput();
    printInput();
}

static void getInput() {
    for (int i = 0; i < baseData.length; i++) {
        baseData[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

static void printInput() {
    for (int i : baseData) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: why do you want to use enhanced for-loop for assigning values?

Comment: Actually this code is working. What u want to do

Comment: I know this code is working.  See I'm a beginner Java programmer. I wrongly assumed that the enhanced for loop can be used as a replacement for the regular for loop for all scenarios.  That is why I was wondering if there's a simple way to do it with Enhanced For loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for-each` loop *hides* the iterator, so you won't be able to update the array with one (at least not without adding a new counter / iterator). Instead, assuming you're using Java 8+, you can write an `IntStream` generator using your `Scanner`. Something like,

```
private static int[] baseData = IntStream.generate(() -> scanner.nextInt())
        .limit(4).toArray();
```

However, this is really just an example, in real life I would prefer code that is a little more forgiving with unexpected input.

Comment: @Econ_newbie: Here in SO if an answer helps you with your problem you may want to mark it as the answer. That's how being thankful applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int[] baseData = IntStream.generate(() -> scanner.nextInt())
.limit(4).toArray();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers here");
    printInput();
}


static void printInput() {
    for (int i : baseData) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

}
```

OR

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int[] baseData = new int[4];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers here");
    getInput();
    printInput();
}

static void getInput() {
    int position =0;
    for(int i:baseData){
         baseData[position] = scanner.nextInt();
        position++;
    }
}

static void printInput() {
    for (int i : baseData) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

}
```